# About the usage of vocoders

Tags: audio, deep-learning, voice, speech-synthesis

I'm quite new to AI and I'm currently developing a model for non-parallel voice conversions. One confusing problem that I have is the use of vocoders.

So my model needs Mel spectrograms as the input and the current model that I'm working on is using the MelGAN vocoder ([Github link](https://github.com/descriptinc/melgan-neurips)) which can generate 22050Hz Mel spectrograms from raw wav files (which is what I need) and back. I recently tried WaveGlow Vocoder ([PyPI link](https://pypi.org/project/waveglow-vocoder/)) which can also generate Mel spectrograms from raw wav files and back.

But, in other models such as,
[WaveRNN](https://github.com/fatchord/WaveRNN) , [VocGAN](https://github.com/rishikksh20/VocGAN) , [WaveGrad](https://github.com/ivanvovk/WaveGrad)
There's no clear explanation about wav to Mel spectrograms generation. Do most of these models don't require the wav to Mel spectrograms feature because they largely cater to TTS models like Tacotron? or is it possible that all of these have that feature and I'm just not aware of it?

A clarification would be highly appreciated.

Comment: There is no such thing as "wav to mel spectrogram generation" (or you are using unusual wording here). A mel spectrogram is just a short-time Fourier transform of the waveform, followed by multiplication with a mel filter matrix. This is a simple operation and you can use e.g. [librosa](https://librosa.org/doc/0.8.0/generated/librosa.feature.melspectrogram.html#librosa.feature.melspectrogram) for this. Libraries like Tensorflow or Pytorch also have similar functions. To be honest I don't really understand the question, maybe you can clarify what exactly you need and where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What I meant from "wav to Mel spectrogram" is converting a ".wav" file to a Mel spectrogram(what you mentioned was correct) and yes, I've seen librosa and torchaudio also have that option but aren't there any differences between using a vocoder to do this and a regular library like that? like will every method do the operation(to create a mel spectrogram) in the same manner?

Comment: I decided to expand my next comment into an answer. I hope it helps (and isn't too much rambling...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How neural vocoders handle audio -> mel

Check e.g. this part of the MelGAN code: https://github.com/descriptinc/melgan-neurips/blob/master/mel2wav/modules.py#L26

Specifically, the `Audio2Mel` module simply uses standard methods to create log-magnitude mel spectrograms like this:

- Compute the STFT by applying the Fourier transform to windows of the input audio,
- Take the magnitude of the resulting complex spectrogram,
- Multiply the magnitude spectrogram by a mel filter matrix. Note that they actually get this matrix from `librosa`!
- Take the logarithm of the resulting mel spectrogram.

### Regarding the confusion

Your confusion might stem from the fact that, usually, authors of Deep Learning papers only mean their mel-to-audio "decoder" when they talk about "vocoders" -- the audio-to-mel part is always *more or less* the same. I say this might be confusing since, to my understanding, the classical meaning of the term "vocoder" includes both an encoder and a decoder.

Unfortunately, these methods will not always work *exactly* in the same manner as there are e.g. different methods to create the mel filter matrix, different padding conventions etc.

For example, `librosa.stft` has a `center` argument that will pad the audio before applying the STFT, while `tensorflow.signal.stft` does not have this (it would require manual padding beforehand).

An example for the different methods to create mel filters would be the `htk` argument in `librosa.filters.mel`, which switches between the "HTK" method and "Slaney". Again taking Tensorflow as an example, `tf.signal.linear_to_mel_weight_matrix` does *not* support this argument and always uses the HTK method. Unfortunately, I am not familiar with `torchaudio`, so I don't know if you need to be careful there, as well.

Finally, there are of course many parameters such as the STFT window size, hop length, the frequencies covered by the mel filters etc, and changing these relative to what a reference implementation used may impact your results. Since different code repositories likely use slightly different parameters, I suppose the answer to your question "will every method do the operation(to create a mel spectrogram) in the same manner?" is "not really". At the end of the day, you will have to settle for one set of parameters either way...

### Bonus: *Why* are these all only decoders and the encoder is always the same?

The direction Mel -> Audio is hard. Not even Mel -> ("normal") spectrogram is well-defined since the conversion to mel spectrum is lossy and cannot be inverted. Finally, converting a spectrogram to audio is difficult since the phase needs to be estimated. You may be familiar with methods like Griffin-Lim (again, librosa has it so you can try it out). These produce noisy, low-quality audio. So the research focuses on improving this process using powerful models.

On the other hand, Audio -> Mel is simple, well-defined and fast. There is no need to define "custom encoders".

Now, a whole different question is whether mel spectrograms are a "good" encoding. Using methods like variational autoencoders, you could perhaps find better (e.g. more compact, less lossy) audio encodings. These would include custom encoders *and* decoders and you would not get away with standard librosa functions...